# Spring Boot Application with dependency having multiple datasources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, datasource, jdbctemplate

I am trying to create a Spring Boot Application, with a dependency jar which has got context.xml configured with multiple datasources.

In My spring boot application, I added @ImportResource("context.xml") to the @Configuration class and now, I get an exception that 
"No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 4: XXXDataSource,YYYDataSource,ZZZDataSource,aaaaDataSource".

I read the documentation on multiple datasources in Spring Boot, but unable to fix this issue. Not sure, how I can configure my class, as I cannot change the dependency jar to change the way datasources are configured.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "Primary" attribute on your datasource bean to make your autowiring choose it by default.

```
<bean primary="true|false"/>
```

If you are using Java configuration, use the @Primary annotation instead.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html

```
 @Component
 public class FooService {
     private FooRepository fooRepository;

     @Autowired
     public FooService(FooRepository fooRepository) {
         this.fooRepository = fooRepository;
     }
 }

 @Component
 public class JdbcFooRepository {
     public JdbcFooService(DataSource dataSource) {
         // ...
     }
 }

 @Primary
 @Component
 public class HibernateFooRepository {
     public HibernateFooService(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
         // ...
     }
 }
```

If this still doesn't resolve the issue, you can name the bean, and use the @Qualifier annotation in your java classes, or use the "ref" attribute in your Spring XML configuration.

https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier

```
@Autowired 
@Qualifier( "ios") // the use is unique to Spring. It's darned convenient, too!
private MarketPlace marketPlace ;
```

If you require one of the datasources in the jar and are unable to modify the configuration, rather than importing the xml from the jar, copy the configurations you need into your own local spring context configuration.

Comment: Adding <bean primary="true|false"/> to one of the datasource bean in the dependency jar's context.xml did the trick! Thanks a lot!!!!!!!